# Problem with Joomla component - access to Joomla Framework from out of index.php context

Tags: php, joomla, redirect, joomla-extensions

hi I have following problem. Standard actions on components are in Joomla called like this `index.php?option=com_name&action=MYACTION`. Then I can use Joomla framework in my component e.g for database access.
I am developing component for 3dsecure gateway. In one step of the payment i need validate data sent from bank. So I need something like this `index.php?option=com_name&action=validate`. But the bank adds after this URL another `?` and more parameters, so I think it can't be working..So I want to access my Joomla component for example from `3dsecure.mysite.com/validate.php`?Is it possible?

I simply want to use `JFactory::getDB` and then e.g redirect to any view. I know I can use mysql_connect and create own connection to DB, but it is very ugly:)

Can I somehow redirect the request on my side (create valid url with parameters sent from bank) ?`header(Location:)`??

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Joomla!'s apis outside the framework, unless you provide there al the need dependencies (thus recreating the framework elsewhere), which is pretty nonsense.

Moreover, you can have has many parameters as you want in a component url, it's up to the component router to know what to do about that... So, in you router class of the component, you'll place handlers for every $_GET paramater you need, like those returned from the bank.

If you just don't want to get dirty with mysql_* stuff, use PDO (which is, btw, a better approach in general).

Comment: yes I am understand, I know I can have more params, but problem is the url which points to proper action of my component is stored in payment gateway administration and it alredy contains one question mark and two params..so some script on banks side is adding another question mark after and params..
So would be better redirect to proper joomla url, or create another database connection?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a rewrite rule on the server.

For example, rewrite

> 3dsecure.mysite.com/validate.php(...)

into

> index.php?option=com_name&action=MYACTION(...)

If you are using Apache, you can use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for this purpose.

Comment: unfortunately the response must be from the same URL as the query:(

Comment: No problem there, all this is transparent to the client. The server only rewrites the urls for internal use, so that it parses `index.php` instead of some `validate.php` that doesn't even have to exist.I suggest that you do some reading about SEF with Joomla. It can help you to get a better understanding of this subject.

Comment: oh sorry, it wass pretty late for me:Dyou are right, am I able to rewrite url from subdomain to higher level domain?I suppose yes:)
So these things I am not so familier with, so I will look at this and try to learn it..Thanks for your help